# How to write same modern ES6+ module code for both, Node and browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-browser

I need all simple and in the same folder...  These two scripts are running  with `node  --experimental-modules test.mjs`, working fine:

`test.mjs`:

```
import  myClass from './myClass.mjs';

const x = new myClass()
console.log(x.test)
```

`myClass.mjs`:

```
'use strict';
export default class MyClass { ... etc. ...}
```

But when using with browser, there are erros:

`index.htm`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./myClass.mjs"></script>
    <script>
      const x = new myClass()
      console.log(x.test)
    </script>
</head>

<body> <p>My test page</p> </body> </html>
```

ERRORS:

- SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
- Uncaught ReferenceError: myClass is not defined

---

### See also

[Localhost not loading module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55006392/287948) complementar question.

Comment: Try adding `type="module"` to script tag. Also in your browser example you don't have to export class

Comment: Also note that `"use strict";` is unnecessary in a module. Modules (like classes) are always strict.

Comment: Hi @NenadVracar, thanks, good clue (!)... Now new error, *"Access to script at 'file:///....MyClass.mjs' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The response is invalid"*

Comment: The key, as Nenad said, is `type="module"`. But in the above, what you'd do is `<script type="module">import myClass from "./myClass.mjs"; const x = new myClass(); console.log(x.test);</script>` No need to have a `script` tag for `myClass.mjs` at all.

Comment: @PeterKrauss - The problem there is you're loading the HTML file in the browser directly, instead of using HTTP. Some browsers disallow a lot of things from `file://` URLs. Use a local webserver instead.

Comment: You can use a server or check how to run chrome with CORS disabled.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder thanks, yes, make sense. Moved to my `http://localhost/...`.  Now the error is *"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec"*

Comment: The problem is `.mjs`, you should use `js` for browser instead.

Comment: @NenadVracar  I resolved by a link `ln -s MyClass.mjs MyClass.js`... Now the only error is *"test.htm:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined*"

Comment: The way your code works for me is like this https://jsfiddle.net/nhtozpae/1/

Comment: @NenadVracar - Browsers don't care about the file extension **at all**. (But Node.js does.)

Comment: @PeterKrauss - That's odd. You'll want to look at your web server documentation to see how to tell it to return a valid JavaScript MIME type (`application/javascript`) for `.mjs` files (if you're going to use `.mjs`). Re the error you got after linking: Your code imports the class as `myClass`, not `MyClass`. (Case matters. :-) ) (I'd suggest `import MyClass from "./myClass.mjs"` instead.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, perfect, thanks for all!  Well, better  to delete or preserve this question?

Comment: @PeterKrauss - Glad that helped! You never know, someone doing a search may find your question and have it take them to the answer. Duplicates aren't necessarily a bad thing, they increase the search surface area. :-)