# Localhost not loading module

Tags: javascript, module

I am using modern Javascript `MyClass.js`

```
export default class MyClass {
  constructor(x) {
    this.val=x? x: "Hello!"
    console.log("MyClass:",x)
  }
}
```

at my `http://localhost/myfolder/mypage.htm`,  with the source below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='./favicon.ico' />
    <script type="module" src="./MyClass.js"></script>

    <script>
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    alert(123)
    let x = new MyClass(11);

    }, false); //ONLOAD
    </script>

</head>
<body> <p>Hello1!</p> </body>
</html>
```

Why console say *"Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined"*?

PS: this question is a complement for [this other about using ES6+ with *browser+NodeJs*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54615749/287948).

---

NOTE: using UBUNTU ith Apache's Localhost... Some problem with `myfolder` a symbolic link to real folder? at `/var/www/html` I used `ln -s /home/user/myRealFolder/site myfolder`

Comment: where you `import` the `MyClass`

Comment: Because you didn't import it

Comment: Thanks @MaheerAli, seems the solution... What the syntax for `import MyClass`?  No way to say it at HTML tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import the module before using it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="module" src="./MyClass.js"></script>
    <script type="module" id="m1">
      // script module is an "island", not need onload.
      'use strict';
      import MyClass from './MyClass.js';
      let x = new MyClass(11);     // we can use here...
      console.log("debug m1:", x)  // working fine!

      window.MyClassRef = MyClass; // "globalizing" class
      window.xRef = x              // "globalizing" instance
    </script>
    <script> // NON-module global script
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
       // only works after all modules loaded:
       console.log("debug:", window.xRef) // working fine!
       let x = new window.MyClassRef(22); // using class also here,
       console.log("debug:", x)           // working fine!

    }, false); //ONLOAD
    </script>

</head>
<body> <p>Hello1!</p> </body>
</html>
```

There are two ways to use an imported class:

1. at **module scope** (script `m1`): you can use `new MyClass()`, 
   and can "globalize" instances (e.g. xRef) or the costructor's class (MyClassRef).
2. at **global scope**: to work together other libraries or with main script, use a global reference, e.g. `new window.MyClassRef()`.

All this solution relies upon "static import"...

---

### Optional dynamic import

You can use also *import* with ordinary default `<script>` (no `type="module"`), and no "onload",  using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55007965/287948), instead the last script:

```
    <script>
    'use strict';
    import('./MyClass.js').then(({default: MyClass}) => {
       alert(123)  // async block
       let x = new MyClass(11);
     });
    </script>
```

See [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports).

Comment: Thanks, is working! Well, need `<script type="module" src="./MyClass.js">` , `<script type="module">` and `import MyClass from './MyClass.js'`... Seems very very redundant, no HTML to say `import="MyClass"`?

Comment: ... An exotic alternative  to avoid redundances is to use the *dynamic import* syntax [`import('./MyClass.js').then((MyClass) => {  let x = new MyClass(11)   })`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)