# How to import MyClass as a common class reusable globally?

Tags: javascript, browser

There are a simple and standard way to import a class and reuse it globally?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55006392/287948) is not good: needs an intermediary script... And it is ugly, need redundant declarations, and not seems so performatic. It is very strange:

```
<script type="module" src="./MyClass.js"></script>
<script type="module" id="_the_intermediary_script_">
  'use strict';
  import MyClass from './MyClass.js';
  window.MyClassRef = MyClass; // "globalizing" class
</script>
<script> // NON-module global script
// no way to directelly import here??
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
   // only works after all modules loaded:
   let x = new window.MyClassRef(22); // ... after all is an ugly way!
}, false); //ONLOAD
</script>
```

**There is a way to *import class* without an intermediary  script?**

Note: I **not** need ["dynamic load" to import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55009268/287948), I need to load the class as any other library , with  *traditional static library include*. I can use modern (last version) browsers, with **modern Javascript/ECMAScript** interpreter.

Comment: `There is a way to import class without an intermediary script?` No.

Comment: Script modules are lazily loaded, so `window.MyClassRef =` ... runs after the synchronous script ran.

Comment: Hi @JonasWilms, thanks (!). About intermediary script: hum... no nes in 2019 or ES draft for 2020?  ... There is good justificative/rationale for it?  (seems a "language bug"! Nobody use *class* because nobody can reuse it). About running after "DOMContentLoaded", yes, make sense; there is a way to define an event based "on load  module id"?

Comment: Modules are meant to totally replace <script>s somewhen.

Comment: Hi @JonasWilms, seems that (today is ugly but) in a near future *class/module/export* will work fine (!), and by `import` insted `<script>`, good news, thanks.  In most of the browser's operating today (Chorme and Firefox)  I can use `class`...  My aim here is to **reuse** `class` definitions in any  webpage, only it: can  you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

### Reuse your class with no module

To reuse we **not** need to `export class`, need only to publish the souce-code of the class  into a file, and load it when need it... Valid for any browser? It is working with modern Firefox:

`myInclude.js`

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(i=10) { this.i=i; }
    m(){return ++this.i;}
}
```

`myPage.htm`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>example</title>

  <script src="myInclude.js"></script>
  <script>
    let x = new MyClass();
    let y = new MyClass(90);
    console.log( "debug:", x.m(), y.m() );
  </script>

</head>
<body> etc. </body>
</html>
```

### Class expressions in any export

No problem defining a "class library" in a expression of the *`export` thing*?  Seems correct:

```
// body of the exported thing

// ... 
const theClassRef = class MyClass {
    constructor(i=10) { this.i=i; }
    m(){return ++this.i;}
}
```

them use `let x = new theClassRef(123)` to create an `MyClass` object.

See [Mozilla's JavaScript/Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_expressions)